# React Range Slider value bubble

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider

I am trying to create a custom react range slider. So far everything works fine. I need to display the current value of the slider in the circular toggle button every time (not just on being on-slider being active). As the slider is toggled back & forth, the value should be dynamically changing on the circular toggle button.
Something like this:

[image]

I tried using react refs to capture the current styles and apply CSS on it accordingly, but it doesn't seem to work.

The link for working snippet:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-worker-qt99n?file=/src/customSlider.js

Any help to resolve the same appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in your code:

- the `<output>` is hidden with `display: none`
- you need `.slideInpOuter` to have `position: relative` so the `<output>` is positioned according to `.slideInpOuter`
- `thumbwidth` should be 35, because width of the thumb is set to `35px` in `sliderThumbStyles`
- `top` css value should be the same for thumb and output
- `line-height` for output should be `35px` to center text vertically
- you are using css `calc` incorrectly

besides all of this, it seems you cannot destruct `thumbwidth` from the ref, you need to use `.getAttribute` like this `currentValueRef.current.getAttribute("thumbwidth")`

You can see it working here with all the required changes https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-http-5tqex?file=/src/customSlider.js

I had to add an useEffect hook to update style on first render